# Flutter vertical PageView issue with SliverAppBar

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to have the swipe effect of a vertical PageView and the effect the SliverAppBar.

If I set the **scrollDirection: Axis.vertical** of the **PageView.builder** and swipe vertical, when I swipe back I can't get the SliverAppBar.

Setting **scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal** the SliverAppBar works, but as mentioned I need it vertical.

I didn't found any good way to fix this yet, can you help me to understand?
**My final objective is** to have the first "screen" with buttons (that´s why I am using the SliverAppBar) and next screens will be a fullscreen image gallery. If you have a better solution that don´t use Slivers or PageView, please advise me.

```
     @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.85,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                background: Image.network(
                  'https://source.unsplash.com/random?monochromatic+dark',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                title: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () => print('btn1'),
                          child: Text('Button 1')),
                      ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () => print('btn2'),
                          child: Text('Button 2')),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: _pageView(),
      ),
    );
  }

  _pageView() {
    return PageView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: 20,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Card(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Image.network(
              'https://source.unsplash.com/random?sig=$index',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to view the full example or test it on your side:
https://pastebin.com/PXDHVw6k

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `SliverOverlapAbsorber` before `SliverAppBar`;

```
NestedScrollView(
              headerSliverBuilder:
                  (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
                return <Widget>[
                  SliverOverlapAbsorber(
                    handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(
                        context),
                    sliver: SliverAppBar(
...
                    ),
                  ),
                ];
              },
              body: _pageView(),
            ),
```

2. use `custom scroll wheel` and using  `sliver.list` instead of `pageview` and also add `physics: PageScrollPhysics()` to  `custom scroll wheel` to get the same page `snapping effect` as pageview.

```
CustomScrollView(
              physics: PageScrollPhysics(),
              slivers: <Widget>[
                SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                    (context, index) {
                      return ... ;
                    },
                    childCount: ...,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: At the time I solved the problem. But thanks Zahra, your reply might be useful for someone else.

Comment: Hey Richardd. would appreciate it if you explain how you solved it? BTW, it might be helpfull for others if you add your solution as an answer here! Thanks

Comment: I did not liked the sliver effect, so I end up using only a PageView.builder to display my content.

Comment: What about appbar? did you remove it completely?

Comment: Yes I did not used the appBar. It was an image gallery. Without appbar looked better.

Comment: But check this package https://pub.dev/packages/draggable_home it might well you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, BTW, even in **draggable_home** package it is mentioned that "_body is in the form of Column which requires list of widget or a widget. Do not add any verically scrollable widge or you may just disable the scroll._" So I assume a vertical pageview will disrupt the appbar compression  or movement.